# display record for currently logged in user

Tags: asp.net

I want to display records from the currently logged in user. I am able to display records but it displays all the records that have been submitted to the system. I want records based on who submitted information to the data base.

This is my code for the page i want the ideas to be displayed from

```
            // CONNECT TO THE DB
            SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=ICS-40-JBONEY;Initial Catalog=TTXIdeaPortal;Integrated Security=True");
            sqlCon.Open();

            //CREATE A COMMAND
            int userid = Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserCookie"]);
            //SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT [IdeaTitle], [IdeaDescription], [How], [Why], [Category] FROM [dbo].[EmployeeIdeas]");
            SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("ustpGetEmployeeIdeas");
            //SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from EmployeeIdeas where EloginID = ");
            //sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text =  "SELECT * FROM list where user_id = " + userid + "";
            sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            sqlcmd.Connection = sqlCon;



            string ideaTitle = "";
            string ideaDescription1 = "";
            string how1 = "";
            string why1 = "";

            //READ FROM DB
            SqlDataReader reader = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                ideaTitle += reader["IdeaTitle"].ToString();
                ideaDescription1 += reader["IdeaDescription"].ToString();
                how1 += reader["How"].ToString();
                why1 += reader["Why"].ToString();


            }

            sqlCon.Close();
            Label1.Text = ideaTitle;
            Label2.Text = ideaDescription1;
            Label3.Text = how1;
            Label4.Text = why1;



        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you aren't passing any parameters to your stored procedure so it doesn't have any means of limiting the results.

Comment: this is my procedure that i am using

Comment: SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT [IdeaTitle], [IdeaDescription], [How], [Why], [Category] FROM [dbo].[EmployeeIdeas]");

Comment: I made it explicit first to figure it out how do i limit the records based on current user

Comment: Are you storing the user id in [EmployeeIdeas]? If not, it might not be possible.

Comment: that might bee it wazz

Comment: i'm going to try that the lights just flickered